# Different layout file for differenct activites

Tags: android

Should I put xml landscape layout files for ALL the activities in the same layout-land folder?
If there are 3 activities and 3 landscape layout, then how should I name them in layout land folder to be recognized?

I have 2 activities - A and B, they each have 2 lanscape layout in layout-land folder but only activity A can find the layout for landscape, whereas activity B finds the landscape layout for activity A and use it. Why? How to map the landscape layout to its activities?

```
//ACTIVITY- A
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent bmr= new Intent(TdeeActivity.this,BMRActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(bmr,CALLED_ACTIVITY);    

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tdee);
            Button ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
            rdActLevel=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rd);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    showResult();
                }

            });             
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code for the activity B? I am guessing you are doing something wrong when setting the content view for this activity.

Comment: A Parent Activity calls Activity A which in turn call Activity B. When Activity B finishes, it shows Activity A (in portrait). But if I change portrait to landscape, it gets the landscape layout for activity B. (the names are same for Activity A in layouts)

Comment: Somehow Activity B still remains. But How come, I Log it to confirm its end, it finishes and tuns to activity A. Yet if I change Activity A 's orientation, it gets Activity B's layout.

Answer (score 0):

You give them the same name as the one in portrait mode, as long as you put them in the right folder (layout-land) they will be loaded automatically.
And yes you do need to provide a different layout for each activity in landscape if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Android Activity Automatically recognized the layout land. If you put same name layout in android layout-land and portrait mode and load this layout in you activity class then then android automatically  recognized it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a rule, but it is better to anticipate the user experience. If you did not include one landscape layout, Android will resize it automatically when phone is rotated. This may cause bad user experience (like image stretching, bad Widget size or overlapping). If you test your App on many screen sizes in both orientations and are satisfied with the result, then you do not need to add one for every layout.

For the Activity relation, there is no link between number of Activities and number of Layouts (you may have many Activities with one Layout, with minimal changes done via code). It really depends on what each Layout represents.

Fore the last question, you need to name the xml files with the exact same name in `layout-land` as in `layout` folder for Android to map them correctly.

Comment: A Parent Activity calls Activity A which in turn call Activity B. When Activity B finishes, it shows Activity A (in portrait). But if I change portrait to landscape, it gets the landscape layout for activity B. (the names are same for Activity A in layouts)

Comment: Try using `setContentView()` in the `onResume()` method.

Comment: Not working. When Activity A starts, instead of showing its own layout(though setContentView is set), it starts Activity B. Activity B finishes and turns to Activity A. Pls see the edited post

Comment: Now I got the problem, every time we rotate the phone it recalls the activity, thats y my Activity A calls Activity B again and gets layout for Activity B. Is ther any way to know if an acitivity is already running?

Comment: In `setResult` in Activity B, use `finish()` to force Activity B to be destroyed.